# My form is not being canceled with preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a gallery of images and I'm trying to have pagination. I have already done the function in my controller (I'm using `C#`), and the function is called when I click on a button to go next page. The problem is that if I do it this way, I refresh all the page, and now I'm using `Jquery` to only refresh the images gallery.

My problem is that when I click on a submit button, is like `e.preventDefault();` is ignored.

This is my submit form:

```
<form action="~/Home/pagination" method="post" id="ajax_submit_next">
         <button id="btnNext" value="@item.getNumeroEntrega()" type="submit">
               Siguiente
          </button>
</form>
```

And this is my jquery:

```
$("#ajax_submit_next").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
     console.log("prevent Default");

    var data = {
        'paginacion': 'siguiente',
        'entrega': $("#btnNext").val()
    }
    console.log(data)

    $.ajax({

        url: '/Home/pagination/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
})
```

The `Js file` is working because I have more functions that are working well,

Why is this happening?

Comment: this seems to be working correctly, why do you say that it is not?

Comment: I found the same as @markfila, but two questions for you: why is the button type "submit" and not "button", and why is there a form at all (or have other elements in the form been omitted)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just see here it's working may be other things affect your code from being executing.

**WORKING CODE SNIPPET**

```js
$("#ajax_submit_next").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("prevent Default");

  var data = {
    paginacion: "siguiente",
    entrega: $("#btnNext").val(),
  };
  console.log(data);

  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/pagination/",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
      console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="~/Home/pagination" method="post" id="ajax_submit_next">
    <button id="btnNext" value="@item.getNumeroEntrega()" type="submit">
        Siguiente
    </button>
</form>
```

**NOT WORKING CODE SNIPPET**

```js
const errVar = 10;
errVar = 20;
$("#ajax_submit_next").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("prevent Default");

    var data = {
    paginacion: "siguiente",
    entrega: $("#btnNext").val(),
    };
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/pagination/",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    },
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="~/Home/pagination" method="post" id="ajax_submit_next">
    <button id="btnNext" value="@item.getNumeroEntrega()" type="submit">
        Siguiente
    </button>
</form>
```

here you will see any JS issue will cause your other code. So I suggest you to debug more.